# How to file download in php?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, codeigniter

Hi all I am very new to PHP.

I am creating a career page for my company.When I try to download a file, it properly downloads if I give it a static file name, But when I try to make it dynamic it gives an error.

This is career.php file

```
<!-- ================ Database Connection ============= -->
<?php

include ('connection.php');
session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
        {
        }
            else
                {
                    header('location:index.php');
                }

// ================== Database Connection End ===============
$query = "select name,email,phone,message,cv from career";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Career| Infosyselite</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
       folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">
  <!-- Morris chart -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/morris.js/morris.css">
  <!-- jvectormap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap.css">
  <!-- Date Picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
  <!-- Daterange picker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
  <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="main-header">
    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="index2.html" class="logo">
      <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
      <span class="logo-mini"><b>I</b>ET</span>
      <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
      <span class="logo-lg"><b>Infosyselite</span>
    </a>
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="push-menu" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

          <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <img src="dist/img/logo.png" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
              <span class="hidden-xs">Infosyselite</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- User image -->
              <li class="user-header">
                <img src="dist/img/logo.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

              </li>
              <!-- Menu Body -->

              <!-- Menu Footer-->
              <li class="user-footer">

                <div class="pull-right">
                  <a href="signout.php" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <div class="user-panel">
        <div class="pull-left image">
          <img src="dist/img/logo.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left info">
          <p>InfosysElite</p>

        </div>
      </div>

      <ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="dashboard.php">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
          </a>

        </li>
            <li class="">
          <a href="contact.php"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <span>Contact</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="active ">
          <a href="career.php">
            <i class="fa fa-job"></i> <span>Career</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Career
        <small>Control panel</small>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">career</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
 <div class="box">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Career Details</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Phone</th>
                  <th>Message</th>
                  <th>Resume</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
               <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)):?>

                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['message'];?></td>
                 <td><a href='download.php?cv='".$fileName."''><?php echo $row['cv'];?></a></td>
                </tr>   
                <?php endwhile ?>
                 <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Phone</th>
                  <th>Message</th>
                  <th>Resume</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
</section>
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <footer class="main-footer">

    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2018 <a href="https://www.infosyselite.com">Infosyselite</a>.</strong> All rights
    reserved.
  </footer>


  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
  <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
       immediately after the control sidebar -->
  <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Resolve conflict in jQuery UI tooltip with Bootstrap tooltip -->
<script>
  $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Morris.js charts -->
<script src="bower_components/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/morris.js/morris.min.js"></script>
<!-- Sparkline -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
<!-- jvectormap -->
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-knob/dist/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<!-- daterangepicker -->
<script src="bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!-- datepicker -->
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap WYSIHTML5 -->
<script src="plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Slimscroll -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
<script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#example1').DataTable()
    $('#example2').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : false,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : true,
      'autoWidth'   : false
    })
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php

if(!empty($_GET['cv'])){    
    $fileName = basename($_GET['cv']);  
    $filePath = 'cv/'.$fileName;    
    if(!empty($fileName) && file_exists($filePath)){    
        // Define headers
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($fileName) . "\"");
        header("Content-Type:".$contentType."");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        // Read the file                                                            
        readfile($filePath);
        exit;
    }else{
        echo 'The file does not exist.';
    }
}


?>
```

So please help on this issue.
I want to update it so it automatically take filename from GET parameter  and download the file.

Comment: "_but if i make dynamic then create issue_" What issue would that be? Post your errors

Comment: check this download files automatic http://www.onlinecode.org/download-files-php/ it will help you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to change

```
<a href='download.php?cv='".$fileName."''>
```

The above had incorrect usage of single quotes

to

```
<a href='download.php?cv=<?php echo $row['cv'];?>'>
```

and possibly change the `download.php`

```
if( !empty( $_GET['cv'] ) ){

    $fileName = basename( $_GET['cv'] );  
    $filePath = 'cv/'.$fileName;  

    if( !empty( $fileName ) && file_exists( $filePath ) ){    
        // Define headers

        $basename=basename( $fileName );
        $contentType='application/octet-stream';

        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename={$basename}");
        header("Content-Type: {$contentType}");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        if( $file = @fopen( $filePath, 'rb' ) ) {
            while( !@feof( $file ) and ( connection_status()==0 ) ) {
                print( fread( $file, 1024*8 ) );
                flush();
            }
            @fclose( $file );
        }
        exit;

    }else{
        echo 'The file does not exist.';
    }
}
```